# What is the purpose of google guava libraries?

Tags: java, guava

They seem identical to java.util counterparts.
In a project I have to review these apis are used and an external jar is present for that.

But...in what they are different from java.util ones?

Comment: _They seem identical to java.util counterpart_ - you dont seem to have compared the 2 in any great depth

Comment: No, indeed...I am just deciding if I need them or I can save some space/dependancy. From the code it just seems that I could substitute everything with java.util. So I am asking in what do they differ and what advantages they bring

Comment: Well, just try it; once you have tested it, you will have a hard time doing _without_ it. FWIW, a lot of new interfaces in Java 8 were born in Guava to begin with (for instance, `Function`, `Predicate`, `Supplier`). And of course, immutable collections which Java 8 _still lacks_.

Comment: What is an example of a "java.util counterpart" of a Guava feature?  (Aside from those that were added to the JDK after Guava)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Guava libraries, much like the [Apache Commons libraries](http://commons.apache.org),  are intended to complement the core java libraries, as outlined in the [Philosophy Explained document](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/PhilosophyExplained):

> Guava is a productivity multiplier for Java projects across the board: we aim to make
>   working in the Java language more pleasant and more productive. The JDK utilities, e.g.
>   the Collections API, have been widely adopted and have significantly simplified virtually 
>   all Java code. We hope to continue in that tradition.

That article goes on to explain how they realise that you could implement the procedures they provide to fill the gaps in the core API yourself, but believe there are a number of advantages to using their code:

> - Guava has been battle-tested in production at Google.
> - Guava has staggering numbers of unit tests: as of July 2012, the guava-tests package
>     includes over 286,000 individual test cases. Most of these are automatically generated,
>     not written by hand, but Guava's test coverage is extremely thorough, especially for
>     `com.google.common.collect`.
> - Guava is under active development and has a strong, vocal, and involved user base.
> - The best libraries seem obvious in retrospect, but achieving this state is notoriously
>     challenging.